# Definition of Shift/Reduce conflict in LR(1) parsing

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, theory, lr-grammar

Is it correct to state:

" A shift reduce conflict occurs in an LR(1) parser if and only if there exist items:

A -> alpha .

A -> alpha . beta

such that Follow(A) is not disjoint from First(beta).

where A is a non-terminal, alpha and beta are possibly empty sequences of grammar symbols."

(Intuitively this is because there is no way to determine, based on the top of the stack and the lookahead, whether it is appropriate to shift or reduce)

Note: If you guys think this depends on any specifics of the definition of first/follow comment and I will provide.

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much how it is defined.

Comment: Are you asking if that is necessarilly a S/R conflict, or if every S/R conflict has that form?

Comment: @rici good point, I mean if every S/R conflict has that form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that statement is not correct.

Suppose in some grammar:

- the productions include both:

  - A → α
  - A → α β
- FOLLOW(A) ∩ FIRST(β) ≠ ∅

That is not quite sufficient for the grammar to have a shift-reduce conflict, because it requires that the non-terminal `A` be *reachable* in a context in which the lookahead includes FOLLOW(A) ∩ FIRST(β).

So only if we require the grammar to be reduced, or at least to not contain any unreachable or useless productions, is the above *sufficient* to generate a shift-reduce conflict.

However, the above conditions are not *necessary* because there is no requirement that the shift and the reduction apply to the same non-terminal, or even "related" non-terminals. Consider the following simple grammar:

```
prog → stmt
prog → prog stmt
stmt → expr
stmt → func
expr → ID
expr → '(' expr ')'
func → ID '(' ')' stmt
```

That grammar (which is not ambiguous, as it happens) has a shift-reduce conflict in the state containing `ID . (` because `ID` could be reduced to `expr` and then `stmt`, or `(` could be shifted as part of `func → ID '(' ')' stmt`.

---

Although it's a side-point, it's worth noting the the FOLLOW set is only used in the construction of SLR(k) grammars. The canonical LR(k) construction -- and even the LALR(k) construction -- will successfully generating parsers for grammars in which the use of the FOLLOW set instead of a full lookahead computation will indicate a (non-existent) shift-reduce conflict. The classic example, taken from the Dragon book (example 4.39 in my copy), edited with slightly more meaningful non-terminal names:

```
stmt → lvalue '=' rvalue
stmt → rvalue
lvalue → '*' rvalue
lvalue → ID
rvalue → lvalue
```

Here, FOLLOW(**rvalue**) is {<kbd>=</kbd>, <kbd>$</kbd>}, and as a result in the state {`stmt → lvalue · '=' rvalue`, `rvalue → lvalue ·`}, it appears that a reduction to `rvalue` is possible, leading to a false shift-reduce conflict.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you. To make my statement/definition correct, it could be modified to specify that the grammar contains no redundant/unreachable reductions, and further the items should be modified to be A -> α. and B -> α.β eg not requiring LHS be the same in each case? Will upvote/accept later after you spot this comment.

Comment: @N.McA.: the condition in your comment is not necessarily a shift-reduce conflict. It holds for my second example, but there is no shift-reduce conflict in that grammar using the canonical LR(1) parser (nor a LALR(1) parser.)

Comment: Ah, I was just about to comment asking if that would be the case. Am I right in thinking that a SLR(1) parser, where we do use the follow sets to determine the reduce operations, this would be a conflict? Which implies that the set of grammars accepted by SLR and Canonical LR are different.

Comment: Also, another case where you do get a S/R conflict which I didn't mention is A -> α. and A -> α.β where β derives the empty string.

Comment: And, yes, SLR(1) is a strict subset of LR(1).